# DOCX4J ERROR - No subclass found for /word/media/hdphoto1.wdp; defaulting to binary

Tags: docx4j, docx4j.net, docx4js

I am using the DOCX4J library for writing MS Word documents and started receiving this error message.

**ERROR org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager - No subclass found for /word/media/hdphoto1.wdp; defaulting to binary**

Does anyone known what causes it or how to surpress it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means there is no specific Part which represents content of that type, so it is represented using BinaryPart.

The content in question looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR

It won't cause any problem opening or working with the docx in docx4j, but adding a new image of this type won't be as convenient as is the case for jpeg, png etc.

Tracking enhancement at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/560

Comment: So, I can avoid this error by giving an extension like .jpg or .jpeg to my graphic? Note that the graphic is embedded in the Word template that is used by DOCX4J.

Comment: You should convert your image to a png somehow, then add the png.  See further the issue 560.

Comment: I suppress the error thru log filtering.  Thanks for the suggestion.